# How to write a custom callback success method to store the response in an object and than based on the response do some stuff?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

For an ajax call like:

```
$.ajax({
   ....
   success :function(data){

   },

   error :function(error){
});
```

Is there a way I can grab that data from success function and store it in a variable? Based on the data receive I have to store some property.

If not, can I do something like

```
myCustomAjax({post data}, async, successFn, errorFn);
```

`successFn` would be the callback I want to manipulate from outside based on some behavior.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Yes you can store it in a variable so you can use it outside of that function.  just assigning it like "mynewdata = data;" will store it in the global object, than you should be able access it as mynewdata, or window.mynewdata, or window["mynewdata"]

Comment: well! i don't want to store it in a global variable instead I will use closure or a callback function...

Comment: well it sounds like you already know how to do what you are asking.

Comment: @Mark what is your point ? I am just trying if there is a another way I can extract the response...by the way what is the reason behind vote down ? If you want to vote down please care to give a valid reason..

Comment: @paul I voted you down becuase i thought the question lacked detail, and when provided a suggestion, you basically said you knew how to do what you were asking anyway.  My point is don't ask a question you already know the answer to.  I wasn't intending to give you a thorough introduction to javascript in my comment. Just provide you with an option.  If you had ideas on how you wanted the problem solved they should have been included in your post so that it was clear to the other people reading it.  When I asked you to clarify the question you made no effort to do anything but contradict me.

Comment: @Mark I am not arguing but just said I don't want any implied globals because when you declared mynewdata without var it becomes implied global variable and creates a lot of problem in your application..moreover you can delete a implied variable using delete operator..what I am asking is if I can do it in a different way ...so that I can have more control on my success function...

Comment: I posted an answer with a bunch of ideas, but i'm not sure if any of them help, it sounds like you just want to brainstorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't fully understand your question but the comment box isn't sufficient for what i need to type:  This idea is really only relevant to an ajax call that receives JSON, a JSONP request could do some alternate things.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        function doX() { alert("x"); }
        function doQ() { alert("q"); }
        function doY() { alert("y"); }
    (function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "json.txt",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.mySuccessProperty == "succeeded") {
                    doX();
                    (function () { eval(data.dynamicFunction)(); })();
                }
                else {
                    doY();
                    (function () { alert("Z"); })();
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                // handle error
                alert("error" + error);
            }
        });
    })();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

json.txt contains

```
{
 "mySuccessProperty": "succeeded",
 "dynamicFunction": "doQ"
}
```

the ouput will be

```
alert x
alert q
```

Alot of this feels silly to me, I'm just coding random things you could do but they don't necessarily make sense without the context of an application using these ideas.

Comment: ok i finished it. some of the code is completely random where I use anonymous functions when i don't have to and other oddities. they are intentional to just try and figure out what @paul is trying to get answered.

Comment: thanks! ...actually new jquery 1.5 shipped with promise Api which resolve a lot of my problem AJAX callback...but I appreciate your help ...Now with promise api I can chain my callbacks...

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajaxUrl = "/your/ajax/url";
myCustomAjax = function(data, isAsync, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax(ajaxUrl, {
            data: data,
            async: isAsync,
            success: successCallback,
            error: errorCallback
    }
}
```

is this what you wanted?

and yes, you can store result in any variable you want, but my guess is that you don't really want to - you're dealing with asynchronous programming here, so you may bump into race conditions and other problems. use callbacks.

Comment: Thanks @wildcard...let's say I have to use my callback success function to get some values...lets say my return json looks like

Comment: Thanks @wildcard...let's say I have to use my callback success function to get some values...lets say my return json looks like {"occupation":"artist", "age":"26"}...now can i use my callback like myCustomAjax({name:"mike"},true, function(){update()},errorCallback); var update = (function(){ var something = function(data){//domething}; return something;});....not sure is it possible

Comment: you can, but you need to pass `data` object to your callbacks, so it would have to be `function(data){update(data)},errorCallback); var update = (function(data){ (...)`... not sure why you're wrapping `update` in additional function, if you wouldn't, it could be as simple as `update,errorCallback); var update = (function(data){ (...)` - because jQuery will call `update(data)` anyway.

Comment: your success function in your example above is already an anonymous function.

Comment: i mean self executing anonymous function don't worry about the syntax ..its just a pseudo code ...(function(){}())...is a self executing function ...